# R: making an element required in setRefClass

Tags: r, class, reference

I still don't get it. Here's what I want to do:

```
foo <- setRefClass("foo", fields=list(bar="numeric"), methods=list(
  initialize = function(bar) {
     bar <<- bar
  }
))
```

In other words:

- bar must be numeric
- bar must be set at the start
- bar must not have a default value

But:

```
> f1 <- foo$new(bar=1)
> f1$copy()
Error in .Object$initialize(...) : 
  argument "bar" is missing, with no default
```

OK, how about:

```
foo <- setRefClass("foo", fields=list(bar="numeric"), methods=list(
  initialize = function(bar=NULL) {
      bar <<- bar
 }
```

))

Nope:

```
> f1 <- foo$new(bar=1)
> f1$copy()
 Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘bar’, should be from class “numeric” or a subclass (was class “NULL”)
```

And if I do:

```
foo <- setRefClass("foo", fields=list(bar="numeric"), methods=list(
     initialize = function(bar=NULL) {
         if (! missing(bar) && is.numeric(bar)) bar <<- bar
     }
))
```

Then this is fine:

```
> f1 <- foo$new(bar=1)
> f1$copy()
Reference class object of class "foo"
Field "bar":
[1] 1
```

But I no longer have a creation-time check on `bar`:

```
> f1 <- foo$new() # should give an error but does not!
>
```

Help!

Comment: This is hard to do with RC because you must always be able to call `class$new()` without errors - many internal functions create objects that way.

Comment: Hmm... so basically it can't be done? That seems to make specifying types in `fields` pretty useless :-(

Comment: That's my understanding, although there might be something I'm missing.